# How to get part of html code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a large html code, I need certain tags inside of it.

for example, i want to print all tags start with

```
< dev ........
....
... 

until < /dev>
```

So the starting keyword will be `" < dev "` and the ending keyword will be `< /dev>`.

I want to do python 2.7 script to print the tags and in between code until the last word `< /dev>` and I am kind of stuck at that point.

Example:

```
<div title="buyer-name">test
       <span class="item-price">ff</span> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the strings you are looking for ("< dev" and "< /dev>") are unique, you can use `.find()` like this:

```
my_html = "..."
token_1 = "<div"
token_2 = "</div>"
start = my_html.find(token_1)
end   = my_html.find(token_2) + len(token_2) # in order to reach the last char in this closing tag
```

Comment: yes it is uniqe, but i want the script to take the frist keyword <div and print the html code until last keyword < /dev>

Comment: @waterproof if so, my code will give you the positions of the start and end of the string you want to print, so just use after this: print(my_html[start]) and increment the start variable until you get the end location

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_code = "<html>...</html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
mydivs = soup.findAll('div')
for div in mydivs:
    print(str(div))
```